# Python: complexity of check for overlapping ranges

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity

I have two ranges and want to check if they overlap in Python (v3.5). These are some solutions.

**1a**: use set `intersection` with range:

```
def overlap_intersection_set(range1, range2):
  return bool(set(range1).intersection(range2))
```

**1b**: use set `intersection` with two sets:

```
def overlap_intersection_two_sets(range1, range2):
  return bool(set(range1).intersection(set(range2)))
```

**2**: use `any` and range `in`:

```
def overlap_any(range1, range2):
  return any([i1 in range2 for i1 in range1])
```

I've been trying to compute the cost for these approaches, mostly in terms of time, but space complexity might also be considerable.

The [Python Wiki page "Time Complexity"](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) lists for the set intersections (average case):

> Intersection s&t (average case): `O(min(len(s), len(t))` (replace "min" with "max" if t is not a set)

For solution **1b**, I hence assume `O(min(len(range1), len(range2))`, plus two times a set creation from a range. I consider the `bool` function very cheap.

For solution **1a**: `O(max(len(range1), len(range2))`, plus once a set creation from a range.

For solution **2** (`any`): I have not found much documentation regarding complexities, neither for `any` nor for range `in`. For the latter, I assume that a range behaves like a list, which would mean `O(n)` for each `in` call, hence resulting in `O(n*m)` with `n=len(range1)` and `m=len(range2)`. At the same time, `any` should lead to a shortcut as soon as a match is found and the set creation can be spared.

My questions thus involve algorithmic complexities as well as their Python-specific implementations:

1. How expensive is it to convert a range to a set?
2. How expensive is the `bool()` function really?
3. Does `in` for a range really behave as in a list (`O(n)`)?
4. What other implementation details are relevant apart from algorithmic complexity?
5. Ultimately, considering these questions: what is the most efficient way to check for an overlap between two ranges?

This is not easy to evaluate empirically as the actual computation time depends a lot on the properties of the ranges, i.e. how early an overlapping element is found, and their sizes. That is why I am looking for a more analytical explanation.

Comment: `Does in for a range really behave as in a list (O(n))?` In Python 3 definitely not. It is `O(1)`.  In Python 2 it is `O(n)` since `range` returns a list.. I need to find a source for this though.

Comment: @DeepSpace that is a very interesting piece of information! It seems to indicate that solution 2 should run faster, doesn't it?

Comment: Indeed, even for very large ranges. And it can be even faster if changed to `any(i1 in range2 for i1 in range1)`

Comment: @trincot they are actual [Python ranges](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range), created with e.g. `range(0, 5)`.

Comment: Can those ranges have `step` values other than `1`, e.g. `range1 = range(0, 100, 5), range2 = range(100, 0, -7)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do that. Instead:

1. Arrange that every range is arranged as lowest-to-highest.
2. if range1.lowest > range2.lowest then swap range1 with range2
3. If range1.highest >  range2.lowest then ranges intersect
4. If range1.highest == range2.lowest then ranges touch
5. If range1.highest <  range2.lowest then ranges are distinct.

The above algorithm is independent of the sizes of the ranges and can handle non-integer ranges too.

Something like:

```
def is_overlapped(r1, r2):
    if r1.lowest > r2.lowest:
        r1, r2 = r2, r1
    return r1.highest > r2.lowest
```

**A more full implementation:**

```
from collections import namedtuple

class Range(namedtuple('Range', 'lowest, highest')):

    __slots__ = () 

    def __new__(_cls, lowest, highest):
        'Enforces lowest <= highest'
        if lowest > highest:
            lowest, highest = highest, lowest
        return super().__new__(_cls, lowest, highest)

def is_overlapped(r1, r2):
    r1, r2 = sorted([r1, r2])
    return r1.highest > r2.lowest

if __name__ == '__main__':
    range1, range2 = Range(4, -4), Range(7, 3)
    assert is_overlapped(range2, range1) == is_overlapped(range1, range2)
    print(is_overlapped(range2, range1))  # True
```

Comment: @trincot, erm, constant? `if r.lowest > r.highest: r.lowest, r.highest = r.highest, r.lowest`

Comment: Also, `range` objects do not seem to have attributes `lowest` and `highest`, at least not in my version and not according to the documentation I found, but you can do the same with `r1[-1]` and `r2[0]`, provided that the ranges are non-empty.

Comment: I did not read the original question as meaning a python range object. I instead thought I was free to interpret the concept of a range in its more mathematical sense of being a bounded region of numbers - ignoring inclusion/exclusion of bounds issues for simplicity.  If given a Python program I would expect that such bounds would be available and *not* proceed to call range(). The above would not work with python ranges with different step values, but again, that is not made clear in the question, (to me).

Comment: I was also wondering about the `lowest`/`highest` attributes. However, instead of calling `range(start, end)` for both ranges, `r1` and `r2` can be tuples `(start, end)`. `r1.lowest` and `r1.highest` can then be replaced with `r1[0]` and `r1[1]` respectively.